# Error al ordenar un arreglo con números negativos con la función sort de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy intentando ordenar el siguiente arreglo que contiene números negativos y la función `sort()` no lo ordena correctamente (precisamente los números negativos)

```js
let aa = [1,-2,3,-4,5].sort();
console.log(aa);
```

Me retorna:

```
[-2, -4, 1, 3, 5]
```

Pero yo esperaba el orden de menor a mayor

```
[-4, -2, 1, 3, 5]
```

¿Que estoy haciendo o interpretando mal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Array#sort( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) ordena **segun el orden UTF-8**, tras convertir los elementos en cadenas.

Según lo anterior, primero toma el `-`, y despues el número en si. Y, en código UTF-8, el valor de `2` es **menor** que el valor de `4`. Y el del signo `-`, menor al de cualquier dígito o letra.

Si quieres ordenar el contenido como números, has de pasarle una función como argumento, del tipo

```
SortFunction( a, b )
```

Dicha función recibirá 2 de los valores del array, y ha de devolver

- `< 0` si `a < b`
- `== 0` si `a == b`
- `> 0` si `a > b`

Ejemplo:

```
[1,-2,3,-4,5].sort( function( a, b ) { return a < b ? -1 : 1; } );
```

Salida:

> [-4, -2, 1, 3, 5]

```js
 console.log([1,-2,3,-4,5].sort( function( a, b ) { return a < b ? -1 : 1; } ));
```

Nota: en el ejemplo, es seguro que 2 elementos nunca serán iguales, por lo que nos ahorramos el comprobarlo (nunca devolvemos `0`).

Comment: Pongan esto en la wiki o algo. Esta pregunta siempre salía en el SO de al lado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente